# How to call retrofit api call in sequence of 5sec after onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) event on map

Tags: android, performance, google-maps, retrofit2, android-maps-v2

I am working on google map with retrofit2 api call.

on every camera change i have to call api.

problem is when user swipe/pinch-zoom on map every time onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) method will fire and my api call also.

so multiple time api call are running and because of this my output on map is ruined completely.

```
@Override
public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    camerachange();
}

public void camerachange() {
   Log.e("temp", "camera change");
   // jarray = new JSONArray();
   jarray = new ArrayList<String>();

   LatLngBounds bounds = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;

   jarray.add(String.valueOf(bounds.southwest.latitude));
   jarray.add(String.valueOf(bounds.southwest.longitude));
   jarray.add(String.valueOf(bounds.northeast.latitude));
   jarray.add(String.valueOf(bounds.northeast.longitude));

   getPropertyList(jarray, 1) // this function has my retrofit call.
}
```

guys please help me with this concern.

main concern is multiple time call should not be there it must take last swipe/pinch-zoom effect.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `OnMapLoadedCallback`. From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback):

> **public abstract void onMapLoaded ()**
>
> Called when the map has finished rendering. This will only be called once. You must request another callback if you want to be notified again.

So, you need to set an initial `setOnMapLoadedCallback` for your map for example on the `onMapReady` method:

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.setOnMapLoadedCallback(this);
}
```

And then reset a new `setOnMapLoadedCallback` every time the event is consumed:

```
public void onMapLoaded() {
    //TODO: Do your stuff

    map.setOnMapLoadedCallback(this);
}
```

Also, take into account hte disclaimer from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback):

> This event will not fire if the map never loads due to connectivity issues, or if the map is continuously changing and never completes loading due to the user constantly interacting with the map.

Comment: I said whenever user swipe on map one api call will be fire and response will list of marker will be plotted on map. So if user swipe continuously then last swipe effect should be reflect on api call. and recently what happened is every time api call is fire and response is continuously change